# Continue function after previous function ended

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, asynchronous, pdfkit

I'm building a script to create a pdf file for all the store products using PDFkit.

So I have a for-loop that loops through the pages:

```
// see the range of buffered pages
const range = doc.bufferedPageRange(); // => { start: 0, count: 2 }
for (
  i = range.start, end = range.start + range.count, range.start <= end;
  i < end;
  i++
) {
  utils.generateHeader(doc); //generate header => here is the problem
  console.log(1); //gets called after"utils.generateHeader(doc);" is finished executing

  doc.switchToPage(i);
  doc
    .font(robotoReg)
    .fontSize(16)
    .text(`Page ${i + 1} of ${range.count}`);
  utils.generateFooter(doc);
}
```

Next, I have a problem that `utils.generateHeader(doc);` needs to download the product image in order to insert the image to the pdf:

```
const download = (url, path, callback) => {
  request.head(url, (err, res, body) => {
    request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path)).on("close", callback);
  });
};

const utils = {
  generateHeader:  (doc) => {
    let url =
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/814499/pexels-photo-814499.jpeg";

    const path = "./images/image.png";
     download(url, path, () => {
      console.log(1);
      doc
        .image(path, 50, 45, { width: 50 })
        .fillColor("#444444")
        .fontSize(20)
        .text("ACME Inc.", 110, 57)
        .fontSize(10)
        .text("123 Main Street", 200, 65, { align: "right" })
        .text("New York, NY, 10025", 200, 80, { align: "right" })
        .moveDown();
      console.log(3);
    });

  
    console.log(2); //this gets called on time 
  }}
```

Now the problem is that this gets executed but the image didn't get downloaded yet. so after the script executes all the functions, the image gets downloaded and tries to insert it in the pdf file and I get the error: `Error [ERR_STREAM_PUSH_AFTER_EOF]: stream.push() after EOF`

So, what I need is that first the `utils.generateHeader(doc);` waits for the image to be downloaded, then the for-loop should continue to execute the rest of the script,
but I'm a bit confused about how to all this async.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check for async await once

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi yes, I know but how do I implement it?

Comment: Please check this for implementation  https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/async-await-javascript-5038668ec6eb#:~:text=The%20await%20operator%20is%20used,not%20the%20whole%20program%20execution.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi I read the article, (amazing article I must say) I'm still having a hard time trying to understand where I'm wrong, I tried adding the async await in numerous places in my code, but it still executes everything before the image is actually downloaded. can you please be more specific? thanks, bruv